# Why there was Amrit under the Naabhi(Navel) of Ravana? Is it true?

Tags: ravana

Why there was Amrit under the Naabhi(Navel) of Ravana?  Is it true?
What does our scripture say about how Ravana got the Amrit in his Naabhi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following his initial training, Ravana performed an intense penance
>   (or tapasya) to brahma, lasting several years. During his penance,
>   Ravana chopped off his head 10 times as a sacrifice to appease him.
>   Each time he sliced his head off a new head arose, thus enabling him
>   to continue his penance. At last, brahma, pleased with his austerity,
>   appeared after his 10th decapitation and offered him a boon. **Ravana**
>   **asked for immortality, which brahma refused to give,** **but gave him the**
>   **celestial nectar of immortality. The nectar of immortality, stored**
>   **under his navel**, dictated that he could not be vanquished for as long
>   as it lasted.
>
> Ravana also asked for absolute invulnerability from and supremacy over
>   gods, heavenly spirits, other rakshas, serpents, and wild beasts.
>   Contemptuous of mortal men, he did not ask for protection from these.
>   Brahma granted him these boons in addition to his 10 severed heads and
>   great strength by way of knowledge of divine weapons and magic. Thus
>   Ravana is also known as 'Dasamukha' or 'Dashaanan' (Dasa - ten, mukha/anan -
>   face).

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana#Tapasya_to_brahma)

Comment: Bhavin Man Wikipedia should not be used. Anybody can edit and change the content on their. This is like being a slave to the British. Do not use Wikipedia ever again for your sources and information ad knowledge on the epics of India.